# setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false) has disabled 'x' button on window / dialog QT

Tags: qt, qmessagebox

In order to get my MessageBox working correctly (and not shutting the whole application) - I have had to setQuitOnLastWindowClosed to False.

This means however that pushing the 'x' button on my QDialog does not exit the application properly. Any help?

Here is the code:

Main.cpp

```
#include "openingdialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Dialog code:

```
#include "openingdialog.h"
#include "ui_openingdialog.h"
#include "patientsetup.h"
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QUrl>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->okButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(okButtonClicked()));
    connect(ui->guideButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(guideButtonClicked()));
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::okButtonClicked()
{
    psetup = new pmps_f(this);
    psetup->show();
}

void Dialog::guideButtonClicked()
{
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/PMPS/PMPSv1/Instructionsforuse.pdf"));
}
```

MessageBox code:

```
void pmps_f::start()
{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Pressing OK will start the sedation process with the baseline target effect-site Ce of 0.5mcg/ml");
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok | QMessageBox::Cancel);
    msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Cancel);
    int ret = msgBox.exec();
    switch(ret) {
        case QMessageBox::Ok:
        break;
        case QMessageBox::Cancel:
        break;
    }
}
```

Construction of MainWindow:

```
pmps_f::pmps_f(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::pmps_f)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->startbutton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(start()));
}
```

Comment: Connect `QDialog::finished` to `QCoreApplication::quit` ?

Comment: Can you check if your `Dialog` has the attribute `Qt::WA_QuitOnClose`. It is set by default on all windows and dialogs and should prevent the application from quitting when `msgBox` is closed.

Comment: Ok can you give me more information on how to do each of these?

Comment: I should correct this is a QMainWindow...

Comment: If `Dialog` is in fact a `QMainWindow` and it is open when you display the `QMessageBox`, closing the message box should not make your application quit().

Comment: Ah it is actually a QWidget, with a QMainWindow as its parent....

Comment: You create Dialog and the stack and then you add a parent to it ? This can cause trouble. Can you show more code? Like the header and constructor of Dialog.

Comment: I am using QT Creator - so this has automatically created my window as such: `pmps_f::pmps_f(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::pmps_f)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->startbutton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(start()));`
}

Comment: Edit you question and add the code, it will be more readable.

Comment: What is the link between `pmps_f` and `Dialog` ?

Comment: Dialog is an opening QDialog showing info on the software. On clicking an ok button the pmps_f QMainWindow is opened.

Comment: Show the code. You need to provide a minimal working example that reproduce the behavior if you want people to help you. For the moment you have just shown unrelated piece of code, it does not help very much.

Comment: Hi there, added all the code now. Cannot see an obvious reason why MessageBox would close the application...

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with Qt 5.9.2. For me, with `a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true);`,  only closing Dialog will make the application quit.